# SELECT only one row in the case where there are multiple values for a particular column

Tags: sql, unique, distinct, distinct-values

I have a simple 2-column table, where both columns are integers:

```
3;1
1;2
2;1
```

Let's call the columns 'a' and 'b', respectively. 
Please notice that two rows have the value 1 for column b.

What SQL query would allow me to get all rows in this table, but 
only one row (no preference - 1;1 or 2;1) when there are multiple
rows with the same value in the column b?

In other words either of these resultsets is fine:

```
3;1
1;2
```

OR

```
1;2
2;1
```

because we have exactly 1 row for any particular value of b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(A) AS A, B
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY B;
```

Note that it would work equally with MIN, FIRST or LAST